# How can I view all backups made with rman in the last 24h?

Tags: oracle, rman

What is the best way to find backups made with rman in the last 24h.

Comment: See if this helps. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_rman_backup_location.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
list backup completed before "sysdate-1";
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `after` rather than before, if r0tt wants backups in the last 24h ?